# How do I know when to use a struct rather than a class in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, class, struct

How do I know when to use a struct rather than a class in Swift 2.0?

I know that classes allow people to exercise inheritance and sub classing and I see how classes are very beneficial this way. But if that's the case, when would we ever use structs? They just seem like a weaker version of a class.

Comment: Totally the opposite. If you need it  to persist  you will need a class otherwise structs are a better choice

Comment: What do you mean by "persist"?

Comment: it means if you close your app and open it again you don't loose your data. It can be using NSUserDefaults or writing to a plist file using NSKeyedArchiever